# Amazon EC2 1 GB of Amazon Elastic Block Storage snapshot storage being used quickly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[image: Picture of Billing Dashboard]

It seems that my EC2 usage limit is being reached rather quickly. I have deleted all of my EC2 instances and most of my S3 buckets, and none of my EC2 instances even exist in the terminated state. Are there any other services other than EC2 that use the EBS storage? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual lines that appear in your billing dashboard, so we know what you are seeing. The Free Tier includes 30GB of Amazon EBS storage, so please let us know how many EBS volumes you have and their size.

Comment: Hi John, thank you very much for your response. I don't really understand how EBS is tied to EC2, but are there other services that consume your EBS allowance? Thanks in advance for any insight you're able to give me.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon EBS is only used by Amazon EC2 instances. (Well, it is also used by Amazon RDS, but it shows up as an RDS charge, not EBS.)

We are currently about a third of the way through the month, so you'd want to be around 30% of usage.

The Amazon EBS snapshot usage is ahead of that (58%). If this worries you, then you can delete snapshots under the **Snapshots** section in the EC2 console. Amazon Machines Images (AMIs) also use EBS snapshots, so check the **Images** section too.

The amounts are "growing" because they are based on a month of usage. So, 1GB for 1 day is ~ 3% of the month's total.

However, there is little need to panic — EBS Snapshots are charged at 5c/GB/month, so at the current rate of usage you might be charged 10c.

Comment: Seems like it was due to an AMI (EC2>Images>AMIs) and a snapshot (EC2>EBS>Snapshots). Thank you very much for mentioning that in your answer, and thanks again for your response!

Answer (score 0):

There can be another possibility where you run an instance with EBS volumes 'not deleted' even after the termination of instance, it can accrue storage charges also. So delete those ones also in the 'Volumes' section of EC2 instance if its still unused.

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was due to 2 disabled AMIs. When I checked on the console I could see nothing, but there were actually two disabled AMIS and those two were using Snapshots. And those snapshots were responsible for exceeding the free tier limit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).